# Definition of a system of recurrent events

Tags: pr.probability, definitions

[I asked a [version](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747401/definition-of-a-system-of-recurrent-events) of this question on MSE a few weeks ago and didn't get any useful feedback. Apologies if I am just being stupid.]

I am reading the paper [*A note on the Borel-Cantelli lemma* by Kochen and Stone](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1256059668). They say:

> *A sequence $E_1, E_2, \dotsc$ is called a system of recurrent events if there exist independent and identically distributed positive-integer valued random variables $Y_1, Y_2, \dotsc$ such that $E_k$ is the event that $Y_1 + \dotsb + Y_j = k$ for some $j$.*

I note that this seems to be stronger than the definition given in Feller, say, but let's bear with it. Later on they give an example:

> *Let $E_k$ be the event that the simple random walk in one dimension is at the origin at time $2k$. The $E_k$ form a system of recurrent events ….*

This is a recurrent system *per* Feller's definition, but I can't reconcile it with Kochen and Stone's definition. What could the sequence $Y_1, Y_2, \dotsc$ be in the example?

Comment: Link to the m.se question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: thanks. I've included a link. The only difference is that I didn't mention Feller's definition (which I presume is standard) on MSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the random walk starts at the origin. Let $T_0=0$ and for $i\geq 1$ let $T_i$ be the time of the $i$th visit of the walk to the origin after time $0$. Let $X_i=T_i-T_{i-1}$. Then the $X_i$ are i.i.d. (you may like to think of this in terms of the strong Markov property, for example), and they take even positive integer values.

Let $Y_i=X_i/2$, so that $Y_i$ are i.i.d. taking positive integer values.The random walk is at $0$ at time $2k$ precisely if $T_j=2k$ for some $j$, i.e. if $X_1+\dots+X_j=2k$, i.e. if $Y_1+\dots+Y_j=k$.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I was looking for.